# Android zoomable constraintLayout

Tags: android-constraintlayout, pinchzoom, subsampling, android-photoview

I'm new in android and have some questions. The idea is to simulate a book page with some images and text on it and animations that zoom on a column and after clicking a button zooms on a different part of page and so on. I have seen some good libraries for imageView pinch zoom and pan like PhotoView and Subsampling image scale by davemorrissey. I want pinch zoom and pan functionality on entire constraintLayout and all its child views including textViews not just an imageView. I also have seen zoomLayout library  but apparently it have some problem with constraintLayout as a child.
Is there any solution to use the lovely subsampling library for this purpose? if no, where i have to look? any suggestion will be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a bit, I found this library called "GestureViews" by alexvasilkov. it supports constraintLayout and animations! 
https://github.com/alexvasilkov/GestureViews